# Open Alarm Clock from react native app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I want to open a alarm settings screen from react native app .I have opened android **map** from react native button by the **Data URI Scheme** and When I am trying with android **AlarmClock** there is no **Data URI Scheme** . How can I open it .For react native I just use

```
Linking.openURL('geo:');
```

and Intent for map is

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="geo" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

intent for set alarm is

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />
    <data android:scheme="setalarm" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

and I just call it by 
`Linking.openURL('setalarm:')`

I want to open just like a screen from android Clock
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftLO9.png)

Comment: also try to add permission in android manifest: `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM`

Comment: Thank you..... yes  I have also added **<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />** in android manifest. @Cherniv

Comment: intent for set alarm is
**<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />
  <data android:scheme="setalarm" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>**
and I just call it by **Linking.openURL('setalarm:')**